# error when specifying latitude dimension when reading Netcdf files

Tags: r

I want to read two netcdf files (climate data for two years) and combine data of one single grid (lon [15] and lat[15]) to an array (named prec_year), script below.

I got an error:

```
"Error in R_nc_get_vara_double: NetCDF: Index exceeds dimension bound
Var: precip  Ndims: 3   Start: 0,4294967284,59Count: 366,1,1Error in get.var.ncdf   (ex.nc, "precip", start = c(lon[1], lat[15], 1),  :
```

C function R_nc_get_vara_double returned error"

But when I dont specify lat[], for example say "start = c(lon[1], 1,1)", it works just fine. Please help (1) Why i got this error, and (2) how to fix it?

Many thanks!
    --------------------

```
setwd ("D://Historic Climate data/Aphrodyte/Prec_025/join 2 years")
Prec_origin <- c(1:2)
filenames <- list.files(pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE)
 for(i in filenames){
filepath <- file.path("D://Historic Climate data/Aphrodyte/Prec_025/join 2 years/",paste    (i,sep=""))
    ex.nc = open.ncdf (filepath, readunlim=FALSE)
    lon = get.var.ncdf( ex.nc, "longitude")          # coordinate variable
  lat = get.var.ncdf( ex.nc, "latitude")          # coordinate variable
  day =  get.var.ncdf( ex.nc, "time")            # time variable
  #change lon[x] and lat[y] to select different files/locations for comparison
  prec_year = get.var.ncdf(ex.nc, "precip", start = c(lon[1],lat[15],1), count = c(1,1,-1))
    Prec_origin <- c(Prec_origin, prec_year)  #combine all data into one array
  close.ncdf (ex.nc)
 }
 Prec_origin <- Prec_origin[-(1:2)] # delete first two rows-
--------------
[1] "file D://Historic Climate data/Aphrodyte/Prec_025/join 2     years//APHRO_MA_025deg_V1003R1.1952.nc has 3 dimensions:"
[1] "time   Size: 366"
[1] "longitude   Size: 360"
[1] "latitude   Size: 280"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file D://Historic Climate data/Aphrodyte/Prec_025/join 2 years//APHRO_MA_025deg_V1003R1.1952.nc has 2 variables:"
[1] "float precip[longitude,latitude,time]  Longname:daily precipitation analysis interpolated onto 0.25deg grids [mm/day] Missval:-99.9000015258789"
[1] "float rstn[longitude,latitude,time]  Longname:ratio of 0.05deg-grids with station [%]     Missval:-99.9000015258789"
```

Comment: What package are you using?  Can you make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

In the "start" function you need to define the index number, and not the actual value from where you wish to start.

I believe this is simply what you are looking for:

```
prec_year = get.var.ncdf(ex.nc, "precip", start = c(1,15,1), count = c(1,1,-1))
```

lon[1] probably doesn't produce an error because it gives you a coordinate that can be an index (for longitude; 1:360). However, the output is not what you want (if I understood well you're question).

As information, if you would want to select a region based on pre-selected coordinates, you could do this as follows (maybe not the shortest code):

```
lon_select=which(x<=10 & x>=20)
lat_select=which(y<=40 & y>=50)

precip=get.var.ncdf(ex.nc,"precip",start=c(lon_select[1],lat_select[1],1), count=c(length(lon_select),length(lat_select),-1))
```